# MySQL best/first score difference query optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone help me optimise this query?  I have the following table:

```
cdu_user_progress:
--------------------------------------------------------------
|id    |uid     |lesson_id    |game_id    |date    |score    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

For each user, I'm trying to obtain the difference between the best and first scores for a particular game_id for a particular lesson_id, and order the results by that difference ('progress' in my query):

```
SELECT ms.uid AS id, ms.max_score - fs.first_score AS progress
FROM (
    SELECT up.uid, MAX(CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN score ELSE NULL END) AS max_score
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE  (up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725',         '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086')) AND (up.lesson_id = '65') AND (up.score > '-1')
GROUP BY up.uid
) ms
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT up.uid, up.score AS first_score 
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT up.uid, MIN(CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN date ELSE NULL END) AS first_date
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE  (up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725', '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086')) AND (up.lesson_id = '65') AND (up.score > '-1') 
        GROUP BY up.uid
    ) fd ON fd.uid = up.uid AND fd.first_date = up.date
) fs ON fs.uid = ms.uid
ORDER BY progress DESC
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: If your code works and you just want to improve it, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate place for it. Make sure you read what questions are considered [on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there to make sure it's the appropriate place.

Comment: Seems like your query is missing some join predicates. The `fd` view  returns `first_date`, that gets matched to `date` from `up` (in the `fs` view)... but is there any guarantee that this won't match to rows for a different `lesson_id` or a different `game_id` i.e. is there a UNIQUE constraint on `cdu_user_progress (uid,date)`?  To make recommendations, we really need to see the output from `EXPLAIN` and the index definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent any EXPLAIN output or index definitions, we can't make any recommendations. (I noted in a comment that it looks like some join predicates are missing, if we don't have guaranteed uniqueness on the `(uid,date)` tuple in `cdu_user_progress`... there's potential that we are going to get rows that are for a different lesson_id or a score that isn't greater than `'-1'`.

In the query text, immediately before **`) fs`** , I'd be adding

```
        AND up.lesson_id = '65'
        AND up.score > '-1'
      GROUP BY up.uid
```

I'd also wrap the `up.score` column (in the SELECT list of the `fd` view) in an aggregate function, either `MIN()` or `MAX()`, for compliance with the ANSI standard (even though it isn't required by MySQL when `SQL_MODE` doesn't include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`)

---

If I didn't have a suitable index defined, I'd consider adding an index:

```
... ON cdu_user_progress (lesson_id, uid, score, game_id, date)
```

There's some overhead for the derived tables (materializing the inline views) and those derived tables aren't going to have indexes on them (in MySQL 5.5 and earlier.)  But the `GROUP BY` in each inline view ensures that we'll have less than 20 rows, so that's not really going to be a problem.

So, if there's a performance issue, it's in the view queries. Again, we'd really need to see the output from `EXPLAIN` and the index definitions, and some cardinality estimates, in order to make recommendations.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Given that there's not a unique constraint on `(uid,date)`, I'd add those predicates in the `fs` view query. I'd also use unique table aliases in the query (for each references to `cdu_user_progress`) to make both the statement and the EXPLAIN output easier to read.  Also, adding the `GROUP BY` clause  and the aggregate function in the `fd` view... I'd write the query like this:

```
SELECT ms.uid AS id
     , ms.max_score - fs.first_score AS progress
  FROM ( SELECT up.uid
              , MAX(CASE WHEN up.game_id = 3 THEN up.score ELSE NULL END) AS max_score
           FROM cdu_user_progress up
          WHERE up.uid IN ('1671','1672','1673','1674','1675','1676','1679','1716','1725','1726','1937','1964','1996','2062','2065','2066','2085','2086')
            AND up.lesson_id = '65'
            AND up.score > '-1'
          GROUP BY up.uid
       ) ms
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT uo.uid
              , MIN(uo.score) AS first_score
           FROM ( SELECT un.uid
                       , MIN(CASE WHEN un.game_id = 3 THEN un.date ELSE NULL END) AS first_date
                    FROM cdu_user_progress un
                   WHERE un.uid IN ('1671','1672','1673','1674','1675','1676','1679','1716','1725','1726','1937','1964','1996','2062','2065','2066','2085','2086')
                     AND un.lesson_id = '65' 
                     AND un.score > '-1' 
                   GROUP BY un.uid
                ) fd
           JOIN cdu_user_progress uo
             ON uo.uid = fd.uid
            AND uo.date = fd.first_date
            AND uo.lesson_id = '65'
            AND uo.score > '-1'
          GROUP BY uo.uid
       ) fs
    ON fs.uid = ms.uid
 ORDER BY progress DESC
```

And I believe that would make the index I recommended above suitable for all of the references to `cdu_user_progress`.

Comment: The predicates added to the `fs` view query should be on columns from `up`, not `fd`. Corrected in my answer above.